# What is a good indestructible iPad case for toddlers?

Tags: ipad

Does anyone know of any iPad cases that are so indestructible, that you would entrust a 3-year-old with an iPad?

Comment: Note that almost all of these cases only provide protection against cracking the shell of the device: rapid deceleration (i.e., dropping it or smashing it against the floor or a coffee table) will damage internal components. There's virtually nothing you can do to protect against that without a thick impact-absorbing material like an inch of neoprene—and who wants (or even offers) that…

Answer (score 9):

Check out [OtterBox's Defender product line](http://www.otterbox.com/defender-series-cases/defender-series-cases,default,sc.html). I don't own any of their products, but I've heard from others that they're close to indestructible.

More details & reviews:

- [Tough Guys Rock the OtterBox](http://blog.otterbox.com/tough-guys-rock-the-otterbox/) (OtterBox Blog)
- [OtterBox Releases Heavy Duty Defender iPad Case](http://www.crunchgear.com/2010/08/11/otterbox-releases-heavy-duty-defender-ipad-case/) (CrunchGear)
- [OtterBox's Defender Case puts your iPad in a Batman Suit](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/otterboxs-defender-case-puts-your-ipad-in-a-batman-suit/13503) (ZDNet)
- [Otterbox Defender iPad case review: Best rugged case money can buy](http://www.mobilemag.com/2010/08/06/otterbox-defender-ipad-case-review-best-rugged-case-money-can-buy/) (Mobile Magazine)
- [OtterBox Defender for iPad: When You Need Fully Body Protection](http://www.geardiary.com/2010/07/22/otterbox-defender-for-ipad-when-you-need-fully-body-protection/) (Gear Diary)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is one. The glass-front of the iPad is way to big for any case to make handling it completely secure.

If I had kids, I would just stay with them and observe them while they play with my gadgets.

Comment: Oh, it will be her gadget, not mine. Over-generous grandparents.

Comment: This would be a good reason to buy the accidental damage insurance for the retailer.  I bought it and I have a teenager...

Comment: IMHO: Finding a suitable case is a symptom of another much more worrying problem which is the "over-generous grandparents" - but that's off-topic for this site.

Comment: @torbe that’s a question for http://moms4mom.com/ ;)